# Using Checkboxes with PHP/MySQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have figured out far enough to loop through my table and return a list of check boxes that will be matched to a product. My issue now, is i cannot figure out the proper way to loop through them after they are selected and return them as checked/unchecked for the given product. Thought there is some MySQL involved, that part isn't the problem, I know how to insert into a database or update...when the product is selected from a drop down, I need to be able to populate the checkboxes.

Here is the code i am using to initially display all of the categories to choose from...

```
<ul class="categories">
  <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $category = $row['category'];
     $catId    = $row['id'];  
     echo "<li><input class='catCheck' type='checkbox' name='p_cat[]' value='$catId' /> $category</li>";
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? It isn't complete clear in your description.

Comment: Whether you are trying to checked/unchecked the checkbox according to result from returned from query ?

Comment: Do you have a field in the `products` table which represents the `checked/unchecked` state?

Comment: Validating and retaining state of a dynamic checkboxes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887764/validating-and-retaining-state-of-a-dynamic-checkboxes/9888764#9888764

Answer (score 0):

- You should give each checkbox its own name. For example, p_cat1, p_cat2, ...
- Then you must remember the names you gave to checkboxes. For example, if names was p_cat1, p_cat2, ..., you must known count of checkboxes. So, you should put this count in hidden field or retrieve it from database again.
- If you want to set checked state of checkbox you must use "checked" html attribute, not "value":

.

```
echo "<li><input class='catCheck' type='checkbox' name='p_cat[]' ".($is_checked? " checked " : "")."/> $category</li>";
```

- When request comes from client, you should manually iterate through all $_POST["p_cat$i"] variables and get state using something like isset($_POST["p_cat$i"]).

Answer (score 0):

in html page do it like this

```
echo "<li><input class='catCheck' type='checkbox' name='p_cat['.$row['id'].']' value='$catId' /> $category</li>";
```

and in the back end do like this

```
$delete = $_POST['p_cat'];

foreach ($delete as $id => $val) {
    if($val=='checked'){
        $query="DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Invalid query");
    }
}
```